Build Dockerfile on React pnpm Nx Application
I try to build an Pnpm Nx React application, the application runs perfectly on dev mode. I installed Nx globally in my system.
Now I try to build a Dockerfile to create an image for my application, This is the file content I created
# Étape 1 : Utiliser une image Node.js officielle
FROM node:18 AS base

# Définir le répertoire de travail dans le conteneur
WORKDIR /app

# Copier les fichiers de configuration dans le conteneur
COPY .npmrc package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

# Installer pnpm globalement
RUN npm install -g pnpm

# Configure the global bin directory for pnpm
RUN pnpm config set global-bin-dir /root/.local/bin

# Add the global bin directory to PATH
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH


# Installez `nx` si ce n'est pas déjà fait
RUN pnpm add -g nx

# Check if nx is installed globally
RUN if ! nx --version > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "NX is not installed globally"; exit 1; else echo "NX version: $(nx --version)"; fi


# Installer les dépendances du projet avec pnpm
RUN pnpm install 
# --frozen-lockfile

# Copier le reste des fichiers du projet dans le conteneur
COPY . .

# Étape 2 : Build l'application avec NX
FROM base AS builder

# Construire l'application en utilisant NX
RUN pnpm nx build main-app --prod

# Étape 3 : Configurer l'image finale pour l'exécution
FROM nginx:alpine AS final

# Copier les fichiers de build de l'application vers Nginx
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/apps/main-app /usr/share/nginx/html

# Exposer le port 80 pour l'accès HTTP
EXPOSE 4200

# Commande par défaut pour lancer Nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

When I try to build my image, at the step 7 I get the message that Nx is installed globally
#15 [base 7/9] RUN if ! nx --version > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "NX is not installed globally"; exit 1; else echo "NX version: $(nx --version)"; fi
#15 0.904 NX version: Nx Version:
#15 0.904 - Local: Not found
#15 0.904 - Global: v19.6.1
#15 DONE 0.9s

But at the step when it come to build, I get an error that told me nx is not found:
#16 [builder 1/1] RUN pnpm nx build main-app --prod
#16 0.983 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143
#16 0.983   throw err;
#16 0.983   ^
#16 0.983
#16 0.983 Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/nx/bin/nx.js'
#16 0.983     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
#16 0.983     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
#16 0.983     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
#16 0.983     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
#16 0.983   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
#16 0.983   requireStack: []
#16 0.983 }
#16 0.983
#16 0.983 Node.js v18.20.4
#16 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c pnpm nx build main-app --prod" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
    #13 DONE 0.4s

Anyone can help me please.
